# Have intellij use different python SDKs for subdirectories in project

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea, pycharm, python-2.x

I have a python project like this:

```
project/
project/code
project/code/requirements.txt
project/fabfile
project/fabfile/requirements.txt
```

`project/code` is a Python3 project, so I need to use that SDK.
`project/fabfile` has to be python2, because Fabric currently doesn't support python3.

On the command line I have two virtualenvs to manage this, but inside IntelliJ (With the python plugin), I have my SDK set to Python3 with my virtualenv for the project SDK. As a result, it isn't detecting the different requirements in fabfile/, and is marking python2 syntax as errors.

How can I get it to use different SDKs for these?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IntelliJ IDEA, you can set up a multi-module project, and assign a different interpreter to each module. Create one module with 'code' as the content root, and another with 'fabfile' as the content root.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I don't think can you use different interpreters simultaneously

You would have to switch interpreters on each project

Go to Preferences > Project Interpreter and point the interpreter to your virtual env(s)

Comment: What if it's one project? It's all in one git repo, so I'd rather not have to treat it as an entirely new project root.

Comment: How would the project run at all if they need two separate interpreters though?

Comment: It's one intellij "project" (the grouping for editor windows and shared settings). It doesn't run together; fabric is an automation tool that we use for deployment and other logistics.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is changing the interpreter when switching from editing /code to /fabfile and vice versa. 

You just have to remember to make the switch when trying to run it. 

I guess you can think of it as the equivalent to using the different virtualenv path from terminal, except with a GUI ;)